# Error: Result of a function cannot be produced

Tags: r

```
result1 <- function(a){
b <- nrow(celld[celld$CellType == "B" & celld$Donor =="a",])/nrow(celld[celld$Donor == "a",])
b
}

result1(F22)
```

The result is NaN.
F22 is one of the donors. I want to imply 2 conditions to a data frame at the same time, is this the reason why the error occurs? Or a function cannot recognize a text?

Comment: the `/` line must be moved up one, as in `nrow(.) / nrow(.)`, not split across two lines.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. If you could include some sample data and your expected output in the question, this would help others find a solution.